# Funny issue using + in mail body

Tags: powershell

- List item

Here is a weird one.  $body is buildt with

a loop adding 30 - 100 lines:
$body += "+ $stuff `n"

The problem is if I use in $body a plus (+), it takes each line in the body and splits it to half the line size and continues it on the next line:

Example,

The line is actually:

- moon|glowing so nice today|buy gold now and get really rich soon

It gets changed to (stackoverflow changed my (+) to a bullet.  Just note that there is a plus in front of the next two lines).

- moon|glowing so nice today|buy gold now
- moon|and get really rich soon

If I change the plus (+) to the word Add, I get in the email body:

Add moon|glowing so nice today|buy gold now and get really rich soon

I would like to use the plus (+) as that is the same format another program uses with +/- of lines in the body of the email.  Any ideas how to get this working?

```
    function mailalert($body) {
        $SMTPserver = "mailhost.domain.com"
        $from = "replies-disabled@domain.com"
        $to = "joe@domain.com"
        $subject = "Report for Stuff"
        $mailer = new-object Net.Mail.SMTPclient($SMTPserver)
        $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage($from, $to, $subject, $body)
        $mailer.send($msg) 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$body = "$body $stuff `n"
```

in your loop.

Escape any troublesome characters using a " ` ".

```
$body = "$body `+ $stuff `n"
```

Comment: Where is the plus (+)?  I do not think $body = "+ $body $stuff `n" will get the result will it?

Comment: It was ugly!  It puts something like ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++body1 `n body2 `n body3 `n...

Comment: Why did you leave the +'s in there? I must have misunderstood what you need from this..

Comment: The message needs the plus or minus character at the beginning of the message to indicate an add or remove of something.  It is a required part of the message.  It is also what is causing something quirky with the mail unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I abandoned Net.Mail.SMTPclient and decided to use html as body of text to get around this:

```
    function mailalert($diff) {
        $SMTPserver = "mailhost.domain.com"
        $smtp = New-Object system.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPserver)
        $mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
        $mail.From = "replies-disabled@domain.com"
        $mail.To.Add("joe@domain.com")
        $mail.Subject = "Report for stuff"
        $mail.Body = $diff
        $mail.IsBodyHtml = $true
        $smtp.Send($mail)
    }
```

I changed all use of `n to 
 and tada it works.  It still is a bit perplexing why the other way did not work.  I see another issue where email addresses with pluses in them was being addressed, so I wonder if fixing that broke this.  :)